# Javascript particles background parallax

Tags: javascript, canvas, parallax, particles.js

So I'm currently working on a website with particles background (using [particle.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/)) and I've got the right configurations I want.

But I want to implement something like this [EPFL](https://rapport-annuel.epfl.ch/en/2018/) background parallax effect on scroll.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? Is it possible using particle.js or is there an existing library that can do this?

Also, the animation (on scroll) of those dots connected with red lines - like a line graph.
[image: like a line graph]

Comment: Share some code...

Comment: @BrettGregson what code? I already said I want "to implement" the parallax effect. I have no code to share because I don't know what to do to achieve it. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: And particle.js doesn't have any parallax options of some kind - it just moves independently from scrolling.

Comment: The website you shared looks like it's using Three.js, I would recommend doing the same. The examples page will give you an idea of how it works, maybe there is something you can use as a start on there: https://threejs.org/examples/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out gsap it allows you to create lovely animations and it pretty fast.
https://greensock.com/gsap/

Comment: I've already looked at gsap but it's a pretty big library and I'm not an expert on canvas animations. Can you be more specific on what I should use on gsap (i.e related to canvas)?